# Gradle implementation not importing gradle module into gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, java-8, build.gradle

I have created two gradle, Let's say **Libary-Project** and **TestProject** in the same eclipse workspace folder.
Below are the **build.gradle** and **settings.gradle** for Library Project. 
**Library Project build.gradle**

```
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java-library'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

version = '0.1.0'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes('Implementation-Title': project.name,
                   'Implementation-Version': project.version)
    }
}
```

**Library Project settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'Library-Project'
```

Now Let's See Test Project **build.gradle** and **settings.gradle**, where I am importing Library Project.

**Test Project build.gradle**

```
/*
 * This build file was generated by the Gradle 'init' task.
 *
 * This generated file contains a sample Java Library project to get you started.
 * For more details take a look at the Java Libraries chapter in the Gradle
 * user guide available at https://docs.gradle.org/3.5/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
 */

// Apply the java-library plugin to add support for Java Library
apply plugin: 'java-library'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    // Use jcenter for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // This dependency is exported to consumers, that is to say found on their compile classpath.
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'

    implementation project(':Libary-Project')
    // This dependency is used internally, and not exposed to consumers on their own compile classpath.
   implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Test Project settings.gradle**

```
include ':Library-Project'
rootProject.name = 'TestProject'
```

Whenever I Try to refresh Gradle Test Project, I am receiving following error.

> Synchronize Gradle projects with workspace failed due to an error
>   connecting to the Gradle build. The supplied build action failed with
>   an exception.
>
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration
>   ':compileClasspath'. Project : declares a dependency from
>   configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'default' which is not
>   declared in the descriptor for project
>   :Library-Project.
>   org.gradle.tooling.BuildActionFailureException: The supplied build
>   action failed with an exception.  at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:62)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)    at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invokeRun(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:170)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.invoke(ConnectionAwareLauncherProxy.java:160)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy32.run(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$1.get(DefaultModelProvider.java:112)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider$3.call(DefaultModelProvider.java:142)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4724)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3522)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2315)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2278)
>     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2193)
>     at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3932)     at
>   com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4721)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.getFromCache(DefaultModelProvider.java:153)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeOperation(DefaultModelProvider.java:138)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.executeBuildActionExecuter(DefaultModelProvider.java:108)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchModels(DefaultModelProvider.java:78)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.DefaultModelProvider.fetchEclipseGradleProjects(DefaultModelProvider.java:99)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.fetchEclipseProjects(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:91)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.synchronizeBuild(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:81)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.runToolingApiJob(SynchronizeGradleBuildsJob.java:73)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob$1.run(ToolingApiJob.java:73)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiInvoker.invoke(ToolingApiInvoker.java:62)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.util.progress.ToolingApiJob.run(ToolingApiJob.java:70)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:56) Caused
>   by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all
>   dependencies for configuration ':compileClasspath'.   at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:97)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:69)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:463)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$4.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:455)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:455)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:431)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$1400(DefaultConfiguration.java:109)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationResolvableDependencies.getResolutionResult(DefaultConfiguration.java:963)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.resolver.DefaultIdeDependencyResolver.getIncomingResolutionResult(DefaultIdeDependencyResolver.java:216)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.resolver.DefaultIdeDependencyResolver.getIdeProjectDependencies(DefaultIdeDependencyResolver.java:57)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.IdeDependenciesExtractor.extractProjectDependencies(IdeDependenciesExtractor.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.EclipseDependenciesCreator.createProjectDependencies(EclipseDependenciesCreator.java:70)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.EclipseDependenciesCreator.createDependencyEntries(EclipseDependenciesCreator.java:56)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.ClasspathFactory.createDependencies(ClasspathFactory.java:69)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.internal.ClasspathFactory.createEntries(ClasspathFactory.java:46)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.resolveDependencies(EclipseClasspath.java:318)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.model.EclipseClasspath.mergeXmlClasspath(EclipseClasspath.java:325)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.EclipseModelBuilder.populate(EclipseModelBuilder.java:151)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.EclipseModelBuilder.buildAll(EclipseModelBuilder.java:100)
>     at
>   org.gradle.plugins.ide.internal.tooling.EclipseModelBuilder.buildAll(EclipseModelBuilder.java:68)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.BuildControllerAdapter.getModel(BuildControllerAdapter.java:58)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.CompositeModelQuery.collectRootModels(CompositeModelQuery.java:42)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.CompositeModelQuery.execute(CompositeModelQuery.java:37)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.buildship.core.workspace.internal.CompositeModelQuery.execute(CompositeModelQuery.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:53)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.buildResult(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.access$000(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:38)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$1.buildFinished(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor12.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:305)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:285)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:273)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:260)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:221)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:145)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:315)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:225)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:138)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy14.buildFinished(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:117)
>     at
>   org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:100)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.configure(GradleBuildController.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:65)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:88)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:31)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   org.gradle.internal.component.model.ConfigurationNotFoundException:
>   Project : declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to
>   configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for
>   project :AO-Product-VideoToClips-Library.     at
>   org.gradle.internal.component.model.LocalComponentDependencyMetadata.selectConfigurations(LocalComponentDependencyMetadata.java:124)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.component.local.model.DslOriginDependencyMetadataWrapper.selectConfigurations(DslOriginDependencyMetadataWrapper.java:65)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:303)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:270)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:167)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:104)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:92)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:45)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)    at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:189)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
>     at
>   org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:199)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:65)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:43)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:134)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:74)
>     at
>   org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:67)
>     ... 98 more

Any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: From your setting.gradle, it looks like your TestProject is root level, while  Libary-Project is the submodule, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As, I had already mentioned both the projects are in the same folder structure, as shown below:

- Workspace Folder

  - TestProject
  - Library-Project

To refer **Library-Project** in **TestProject**, update **settings.gradle** of TestProject as shown below

```
include ':Library-Project'
project(':Library-Project').projectDir = new File('../Library-Project')
```